# Evaluating references of a Child Lightning Component body

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

How can I evaluate the body of a child component so that the expressions run in context of the included component?
I am trying to do this in the same way that aura:iteration processes its body.
I have taken a look at the code behind the iteration component however it is mostly under the hood and doesn't run in the same way.

The component I have is called in the following way:

```
<c:Data>
    Data is here: {! v.Data }
</c:Data>
```

I need {! v.Data } to pull data through from the c:Data component rather than the parent component - much like what would happen for an aura:iteration component.

Is this possible?
How would I go about this?

Comment: Question is unclear, please specify what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Good question, I've been trying to figure this one out myself.  Said another way, is there a way to render the facet in the scope of the child component rather than the parent or a way to provide an attribute from the child to the parent scope?  As an example, in Vue.js this is known as a 'scoped slot'.

Comment: Yep - that is it (not used to the terms as I don't use anything like Vue.js). I have played around with it a little and managed to replicate it for direct children but not by modifying the whole scope (including child components of child components). The code used in Lightning can be seen [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/4b89d02ab00e8bdc4cc098928d1d59c6814764c5/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/component/IterationComponent.js) but they appear to be using a lot of hidden framework features. Would love to be able to do this myself.